# IIS 7 - Does the number of HTTP connections matters?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I'm optimizing a very popular website and since the user base is constantly growing I'm interested in what matters when it comes to scaling.

Currently I am scaling by adding more CPU power / RAM memory to the server. This works nicely - even though the site is quite popular, currently CPU usage is at 10%.

So, if possible, I'd keep doing that. What I am worried about is whether I could get to the point where CPU usage is low but users have problems connecting because of the number of HTTP connections. Is it better to scale horizontally, by adding more servers to the cluster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually just adding more memory won't be enough. There are concurrent connection limits for TCP rather than IIS (though both factors do come into account, IIS can handle about 3000 connections without a strain).

You probably won't encounter what you suggest where the CPU usage is low but number of HTTP connections is high unless it is a largely static site, but the more connections open, the higher the CPU usage.

But regardless of this, what you need for a popular site is redundancy, which is essential for a site which has a large user base. There is nothing more annoying to the user than the site being down as your sole server goes offline for some reason. If you have 2 servers behind a load balancer, you can grow the site, even take a server offline with less fear of your site going offline.

Comment: Site is really dynamic... so you are saying that I will rather run into CPU limit then TCP connection limit? Speaking of that connection limit - I already moved all images from the site to CDN and will now get to merging all JS & CSS in just two files - that should help when it comes to number of TCP connections, right?

Comment: I think you would run into a CPU limit in that case. As for images, it will help, especially if you have large files or a lot of them.